# How do I use the code duplicate feature?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I found [this official topic](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_duplicate.html) about this feature in general, but strangely enough, it does not tell me how to use the feature, only that it exists somewhere.  How do I use this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Refactoring tool

- right click on the method you want to re-use
- `Refactor`
- `Find and Replace Code Duplicates ...`

Comment: Ah thanks.  Does this *usually* do something useful?  It didn't find anything that I, as a human, could easily notice.

Comment: @DanielKaplan usually not useful but when it is its brilliant.

Comment: Let me ask that another way: Since it didn't seem to find a very obvious duplicate, in what scenario will this feature work?

Comment: @DanielKaplan it may not be a duplicate. It needs to be the same, not similar.